# Salesforce Date field (add a month/31 days but cannot end on weekend)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have two fields in a particular opportunity. One is the "Proposal Sent Date" which is automatically entered when the user generates the proposal (via Conga Composer). I also have the "Proposal Valid Thru Date" which should be 1 month (or 31 days for simplicity) after the Proposal Sent Date. HOWEVER, this valid thru date cannot be on the weekend.

My question is, how can I turn:

```
Proposal Valid Thru Date (Date)=

Proposal_Sent_Date__c + 31
```

Into a field that will push the date 2 days forward if it is a Saturday, and 1 day forward if it is a Sunday?

For instance, If I ran that report today, the sent date is 5/4/2017 but the Valid date is 6/4/2017 which is a Sunday. I need that to know 6/4/2017 is a Sunday and to add a day to make the valid thru date 6/5/2017 which is Monday

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
public static Date changeWeekendTaskDueDate(Date thedate)
{
    Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(thedate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
    String dayOfWeek=dt.format('E');
    Integer offset = 0;

    if(dayOfWeek == 'Sat')
    {
        offset = 2;
    }
    else if(dayOfWeek == 'Sun')
    {
        offset = 1;
    }

    return thedate+offset;
}
```

This will need to be a workflow if you want to update the field, this can get you started

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_date.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: This can be added directly into the formula field?

Comment: oh it's a validation rule, hm  not sure how you can do that

Comment: The current Formula Field for "Proposal Valid Thu Date" is Proposal_Sent_Date__c + 31. I was just looking for something to put in the formula field to replace the above and make the change.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_date.htm&language=en_US&type=0